# Export pandas dataframe to excel sheet

Tags: pandas

I have a dictionary of dataframes and need to export them to excel.

```
mycollection = {'company1': df1, 'company2': df2, 'company3': df3}
```

I need to export all 3 dataframes to a single excel file using 3 sheets. Each sheet should be named the company number for e.g. "company3".

There are around 200 dataframes in the *mycollection* dictionary. I can use **to_excel** method to export data to excel, but that will create 200 excel files.
Is it possible to export dataframe to sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ExcelWriter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) with iter dicts and write by [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    for k, v in mycollection.items():
        v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=k)
```

Comment: # InvalidWorksheetName: Excel worksheet name 'XXXX_YYYY_promo_194_del_ZZZ_may2017' must be <= 31 chars.

Comment: It seems that I need to truncate long sheet names to 31 characters without duplicating! sheet_name=k[:30] may or may not always work